# Jenkins fails to build with docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to build my Maven project with Jenkins and Docker.

I prepared following Jenkinsfile inside my repository.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('3-jdk-8') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    registryUrl 'https://registry.hub.docker.com'
                    registryCredentialsId 'docker-hub'
                    image 'maven:3-jdk-8'
                    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvnw -B clean build'
            }
        }
        stage('3-jdk-11') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    registryUrl 'https://registry.hub.docker.com'
                    registryCredentialsId 'docker-hub'
                    image 'maven:3-jdk-11'
                    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvnw -B clean build'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I trigger the item, I got this.

```
Started by user Jin Kwon
Checking out git https://....git into /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/...@script to read Jenkinsfile
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential ...
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/...@script/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://....git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://....git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://....git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c9627132515a20c209a6e0d5f14c3779fa1eb933 (origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f c9627132515a20c209a6e0d5f14c3779fa1eb933 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Configure docker.registry(Url|registryCredentialId)"
 > git rev-list --no-walk c9627132515a20c209a6e0d5f14c3779fa1eb933 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (3-jdk-8)
[Pipeline] getContext
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/...
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential ...
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/.../.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://....git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://....git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://....git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c9627132515a20c209a6e0d5f14c3779fa1eb933 (origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f c9627132515a20c209a6e0d5f14c3779fa1eb933 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Configure docker.registry(Url|registryCredentialId)"
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
Using the existing docker config file.Removing blacklisted property: auths$ docker login -u onacit -p ******** https://registry.hub.docker.com
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/...@tmp/950e743c-139b-4e14-93c3-b9fda206b1f4/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . maven:3-jdk-8

Error: No such object: maven:3-jdk-8
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . registry.hub.docker.com/maven:3-jdk-8

Error: No such object: registry.hub.docker.com/maven:3-jdk-8
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/maven:3-jdk-8
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (3-jdk-11)
Stage "3-jdk-11" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins (Docker Daemon) cannot find the image. Or in other words cannot find the registry.

```
+ docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/maven:3-jdk-8
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required
```

You just need to modify the registry URL in the config with `docker.io` like this.

```
 stage('3-jdk-8') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    registryUrl 'https://docker.io'
                    registryCredentialsId 'docker-hub'
                    image 'maven:3-jdk-8'
                    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
```

Or you can omit the `registryUrl` and `registryCredentialsId` since the maven image is in the public registry (Docker Hub). And Jenkins will try to pull it from there by default.

```
 stage('3-jdk-8') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3-jdk-8'
                    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
```